# How to change state when in other page click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

in project i have 3 page

1)i need  when i click in button 'Next' in page 1 redirect to page 2 and show toast Component in page2

2)when click'Next' in page 2 redirect to page 3

3)and when click button 'back' in page 3 redirect to page 2 but not show toast in page2,

How do slove this chalange, redirect work correctly i have problem in show toast or not show in page 2

---page1---

```
class page1 extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.history.push('/page2');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Button
                    title={"Next"}
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}

                />


            </Fragment>

        );
    }
}
```

---page2 - i write state for toast in componentDidMount f---

```
class page2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showToast: false,
            messageToast: '',
            levelToast: 'success',

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.setState({
            showToast: true,
            messageToast: 'Ok',
            levelToast: 'success',
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({showToast: false}), 3000)
        })
    }
    
    handleSubmit = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/page3');
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Button

                    title={"Next"}

                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}

                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

--page3---

```
class page3 extends Component {
    handleBack = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push('/page2');
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Button
                    type={"close"}
                    title={"back"}
                    id={'b'}
                    onClick={this.handleBack}


                />

            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can use query params.. say on page 3 you use this.props.history.push('/page2?showToast=false'); and on page 2 ComponentDidMount() you checked for the query params named showToast and change the this.setState({showToast: }); to true/false depending on it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using React Router, the easiest way would be to use the second argument that goes into the the `history.push` function.  You could do something like:

`Page1.js`

```
class Page1 extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.history.push('/page2', {showToast: true}); 
        // the second argument sets a state value that can be accessed in the `Page2` component
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Button
                    title={"Next"}
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

`Page2.js`

```
class Page2 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showToast: false,
            messageToast: '',
            levelToast: 'success',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this is the `state` argument in the `handleSubmit` function on Page1
        const shouldShowToast = this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.showToast 

        this.setState({
            showToast: shouldShow,
            messageToast: 'Ok',
            levelToast: 'success',
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({showToast: false}), 3000)
        })
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

'Page3.js`

```
class Page3 extends Component {

    handleBack = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push('/page2', {showToast: false}); // set the location state.showToast to `false` this time.
    };

    ...
    ...
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: i use your code but i have Error : in page 2 :  'TypeError: Cannot read property 'showToast' of undefined'    ----------------------------                                          const shouldShowToast = this.props.location.state.showToast;

Comment: You'll need to check if the state variable is defined-- I've updated my answer above

Comment: thanks for help! but not working and sometimes i dont have page 1 and just show page 2 and 3 , i this time i have error : 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'-----------------------------  const shouldShowToast = this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.showToast;

Comment: Are you using React Router?